# Displaying multilingual characters in a Android app

Tags: android, html-parsing, json, multilingual

I am getting multilingual characters in my response. The HTML code of some of them are  中国(Chinese) 日本 (Japanese), हिंदी Hindi [Indian]), 한국의 (Korean). How do I display this characters in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you try it

```
public class MultiLanguageActivity extends Activity {
TextView china;
String ch="&#25490;&#39592;&#27927;&#20928;&#65292;&#20999;&#22359;&#65292;";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    china=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.chinese);
        china.setText(Html.fromHtml(ch));
    }
}
```

Comment: i have used this method at time of downloading json and parsing it to the string, then why this not show the parsed text at that time?

Comment: use string builder and append d datas

Answer (score 2):

you may use textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourInstance.toString()));,i think it resolve your issue